# Sveltekit 1.0 - API call from +page.server.js fails but succeeds from +page.js

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I am running a dev environment with docker compose containiner:

1. fastapi (backend)
2. Sveltekit 1.0 (frontend)
3. traefik to be able to use subdomains. traefik makes the backend available under http://api.localhost and the frontend under http://svlt.localhost

The endpoint http://api.localhost is available in the browser as well as in postman and i can call it in Sveltekit from `+page.js` as such:

```
/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */

const BACKEND_URL = import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_URL + "names";

export const load = async ({ fetch }) => {
    console.log(BACKEND_URL)
    const res = await fetch(BACKEND_URL)
    const { names } = await res.json()
    return {
        names: names,
    }
}
```

**ISSUE 1:** When i try the same call from `+page.server.js`, this is NOT working, resulting in a 500 error `Type error: fetch failed`:

```
/** @type {import('./$types').PageServerLoad} */
const BACKEND_URL = import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_URL + "names";

export const load = async () => {
    console.log(BACKEND_URL)
    const res = await fetch(BACKEND_URL)
    const { names } = await res.json()
    return {
        names: names,
    }
}
```

**ISSUE 2:** I noticed that the API call from `+page.js`does NOT work on page reload. On page reload i get on the resepective page the same 500 error. ONLY when i then click the link to the page the data is loaded successfully.

**QUESTION:** How can i load the data from `page.server.js`successfully and how can i tell sveltekit to load the data on page reload as well?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know much about traefik, but determined from your description, I believe this is because the `BACKEND_URL` endpoint is only reachable from frontend, but not from backend. I guess `api.localhost` is only resolvable from outside the container.

Comment: You can test it out by running shell command `dig api.localhost` from terminal in your host machine and in your container (`docker exec <container_id> -it dig api.localhost`) to compare the result. I guess DNS will not resolve properly within container.

Comment: `dig api.localhost` returns status: NOERROR. `dig http://localhost:8000`, which is what api.localhost resolves to, return status: SERVFAIL. Both issues happen as described the same for http://localhost:8000 as http://api.localhost, so i guess this issue is independent of traefik.

Comment: Calling any API from outside is not causing the mentioned issues. The data is loaded and displayed immediately.